# How to make groupBy to find the first action in R

Tags: r, sparkr

In R I have a data.frame `data` where `head(data)` gives

```
user  action      information 
12    2012-01-01  12323
11    2014-03-02  24445
12    2012-02-05  32234
....
```

I want to create a new dataset that only contains `user` and their birth, ie their **first** action. For `user` 12 it's `2012-01-01` for example.

In sparkR I know how to do this but I was wondering how to do it in R.
In sparkR I simply did this

```
new=groupBy(data, data$user)
new_data=agg(new, birth=first(data$action))
# Making it local (from a DataFrame to a data.frame)
local_new_data=collect(new_data)
```

Now this list can be saved as a csv-file `write.csv("...")`.

Thanks.

**Update**

I had a data set in sparkR where I runned the sparkR-code to get a list of users and their birth. My problem is that I got a new computer and haven't installed sparkR on it (I'm still working hard on this). I simply need one to run my code in sparkR so I can get the list. I have both the **dataset** and **code** ready to execute. I really hope somebody can help me?

**My answer**

I tried to solve it a different way and for some reason it's running very fast. I simply did this since column action is sorted

```
s=data[!duplicated(data),]
```

Now `s` contains users where action is their birth. To only get them I simply do this

```
ss=cbind(as.character(s$user), as.character(s$action))
```

in this runs very fast in R for some reason.

My question is **not** duplicate - it differs much from the 2 other questions some claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, using `dplyr`, it is almost similar syntax as it also have the `first` function along with `group_by` (in place of `groupby`)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(user) %>%
     summarise(birth = first(action))
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(birth = action[1L]) , by = user]
```

Comment: I can run this code in R but it takes extremly long time even for only 10000 itereations. Is there a faster way to solve it?

Comment: @user6678274  I updated with a `data.table` option.  Perhaps it helps.

Comment: I get a clear output but the row with birth  is the same in all rows which it should not be. The command 'action[1L]' gives the first birth and therefore for all rows?

Comment: @user6678274  It is the data.table command that corresponds to the `dplyr` code.  It is grouping by 'user' and select the first 'action' for each 'user'.  So, i am not sure how you are getting the same in all rows.

Comment: It is the last line 'setDF(data)[, .birth=action(1L),by=user ]' . Do you have sparkR on your computer?

Comment: @user6678274  No, I don't have.  But, if you check it on normal R with an example like you showed, it gives the same output